# Generic function with binary operations

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

I have the following function to return the normalized version of an array whose elements could be Int, Double, Float.

I'm getting the error indicated on line 5 below. I thought the Numeric protocol would address the binary operation but I guess not. What am I doing wrong?

```
func normalizeArray<T: Comparable & Numeric>(a: [T]) -> [T] {
    let min: T = a.min()!
    let max: T = a.max()!

    let n = a.map({ ($0 - min) / (max - min) }) <--- Binary operator '/' cannot be applied to two 'T' operands

    return n
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Numeric`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/numeric)
protocol requires addition, subtraction and multiplication operators,
 but *not* a division operator.

I am not aware of a protocol which requires a division operator to which both integer and floating point types conform, therefore you have to
implement two overloaded functions:

```
func normalizeArray<T: FloatingPoint>(a: [T]) -> [T] { ... }

func normalizeArray<T: BinaryInteger>(a: [T]) -> [T] { ... }
```

Note that your implementation will crash if called with an empty
array, I'll suggest

```
func normalizeArray<T: BinaryInteger>(a: [T]) -> [T] {
    guard let min = a.min(), let max = a.max() else {
        return []
    }
    return a.map({ ($0 - min) / (max - min) })
}
```

Comment: Thanks Martin, it's strange that division is left out. Back to the drawing board... I forced unwrapping things to test in playground. thanks for taking the time pointing that out!

Comment: @djeetee: A possible reason could be that the integers are not closed under division.