# Operator Overloading with Tuples in Swift

Tags: swift, function, operator-overloading, numeric, quadratic

## Operator Overloading

### Swift 4.1, Xcode 9.3

I am trying to make a quadratic equation function in Swift.

While working on this, I found that I needed to overload some operators so that I could work with tuples alongside other numbers (`Double` in this case), this is because I needed to use my custom `±` operator. Despite the fact that I was only working with value of type `Double` in my quadratic function, I decided that I wanted to use generics to make my overloaded operators more flexible for future use.

**But–for a reason I don't understand–I am receiving errors regarding the declaration of the overloaded `/` operator.**

---

#### Custom `±` Operator - Working

```swift
infix operator ± : AdditionPrecedence

public func ± <T: Numeric>(left: T, right: T) -> (T, T) {
    return (left + right, left - right)
}
```

---

#### Quadratic Function - Working

```swift
func quadratic(a: Double, b: Double, c: Double) -> (Double, Double) {
    return (-b ± sqrt((b * b) - (4 * a * c))) / (2 * a)
}
```

---

#### Overloaded Operators - Partially Working¹

```swift
//Binary operator '/' cannot be applied to two 'T' operands
func / <T: Numeric>(lhs: (T, T), rhs: T) -> (T, T) { 
    return (lhs.0 / rhs, lhs.1 / rhs)
}
func * <T: Numeric>(lhs: (T, T), rhs: T) -> (T, T) {
    return (lhs.0 * rhs, lhs.1 * rhs)
}
func - <T: Numeric>(lhs: (T, T), rhs: T) -> (T, T) {
    return (lhs.0 - rhs, lhs.1 - rhs)
}
func + <T: Numeric>(lhs: (T, T), rhs: T) -> (T, T) {
    return (lhs.0 + rhs, lhs.1 + rhs)
}

//Binary operator '/' cannot be applied to two 'T' operands
func / <T: Numeric>(lhs: T, rhs: (T, T)) -> (T, T) {
    return (lhs / rhs.0, lhs / rhs.1)
}
func * <T: Numeric>(lhs: T, rhs: (T, T)) -> (T, T) {
    return (lhs * rhs.0, lhs * rhs.1)
}
func - <T: Numeric>(lhs: T, rhs: (T, T)) -> (T, T) {
    return (lhs - rhs.0, lhs - rhs.1)
}
func + <T: Numeric>(lhs: T, rhs: (T, T)) -> (T, T) {
    return (lhs + rhs.0, lhs + rhs.1)
}
```

**1.** *I only receive these errors with the `/` operator, not with any of the other overloaded operators (`+`, `-`, or `*`).*

---

#### Overloaded Operators With Errors (`/`s) - Not Working

```swift
//Binary operator '/' cannot be applied to two 'T' operands
func / <T: Numeric>(lhs: (T, T), rhs: T) -> (T, T) { 
    return (lhs.0 / rhs, lhs.1 / rhs)
}

//Binary operator '/' cannot be applied to two 'T' operands
func / <T: Numeric>(lhs: T, rhs: (T, T)) -> (T, T) {
    return (lhs / rhs.0, lhs / rhs.1)
}
```

***Hypothesis:*** *I think that the fact that I am using the operator `/` within the declaration of the overloaded `/` operator itself–despite the fact that it is being used in a different context–is causing the error.*

---

#### Final Question:

***How do I resolve the errors while still maintaining the flexibility of my overloaded operators?***

---

***Bonus Question 1:*** If I can (I think that I would probably have to return a `String` to accomplish this), I would also like to make a separate quadratic function that can return an *exact* solution?

***Bonus Question 2:*** Also if anyone knows how to make a separate function that can solve a *cubic* equation rather than quadratic, that would be appreciated too.

---

Comment: I don't think a pair (tuple of size 2) is an appropriate choice for the result. I think it would be better to use an enum that can properly model the 3 cases: two solutions, one solution, zero solutions

Comment: @Alexander, do you think it would be a good idea to make a `struct` containing variables: `var a1 : Double`, `var a2 : Double`, and return this `struct` instead. Also, what are the benefits to this?

Comment: No, because that struct can't model having 1 value, or 0 values. You need an enum.

Comment: The `Numeric` protocol does not define a division. If you use `FloatingPoint` instead then your division operators compile. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/49899377/1187415

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is to define `/` when `T` is `FloatingPoint` or `BinaryInteger`, and not just any `Numeric`. Furthermore, I would recommend you use an enum, to properly model the three possible outcomes of a quadratic function:

```
import Foundation

infix operator ± : AdditionPrecedence

public enum QuadraticRoots<T> {
    case two(T, T)
    case one(T)
    case none

    func applyWithSelfOnLeft(_ fn: (T, T) -> T, withOperand value: T) -> QuadraticRoots {
        switch self {
            case let .two(a, b): return .two(fn(a, value), fn(b, value))
            case let .one(a): return .one(fn(a, value))
            case .none: return .none
        }
    }

    func applyWithSelfOnRight(withOperand value: T, _ fn: (T, T) -> T) -> QuadraticRoots {
        switch self {
            case let .two(a, b): return .two(fn(value, a), fn(value, b))
            case let .one(a): return .one(fn(value, a))
            case .none: return .none
        }
    }
}

public func ± <T: Numeric>(left: T, right: T) -> QuadraticRoots<T> {
    return QuadraticRoots.two(left + right, left - right)
}

extension QuadraticRoots where T: Numeric {

    static func + (quadRoots: QuadraticRoots, rhs: T) -> QuadraticRoots {
        return quadRoots.applyWithSelfOnLeft((+), withOperand: rhs)
    }
    static func - (quadRoots: QuadraticRoots, rhs: T) -> QuadraticRoots {
        return quadRoots.applyWithSelfOnLeft((-), withOperand: rhs)
    }
    static func * (quadRoots: QuadraticRoots, rhs: T) -> QuadraticRoots {
        return quadRoots.applyWithSelfOnLeft((*), withOperand: rhs)
    }


    static func + (lhs: T, quadRoots: QuadraticRoots) -> QuadraticRoots {
        return quadRoots.applyWithSelfOnRight(withOperand: lhs, (+))
    }
    static func - (lhs: T, quadRoots: QuadraticRoots) -> QuadraticRoots {
        return quadRoots.applyWithSelfOnRight(withOperand: lhs, (-))
    }
    static func * (lhs: T, quadRoots: QuadraticRoots) -> QuadraticRoots {
        return quadRoots.applyWithSelfOnRight(withOperand: lhs, (*))
    }

    static func discriminantOf(xSquared a: T, x b: T, c: T) -> T { return b*b - 4*a*c }
}

extension QuadraticRoots where T: FloatingPoint {
    static func / (quadRoots: QuadraticRoots, rhs: T) -> QuadraticRoots {
        return quadRoots.applyWithSelfOnLeft((/), withOperand: rhs)
    }

    static func / (lhs: T, quadRoots: QuadraticRoots) -> QuadraticRoots {
        return quadRoots.applyWithSelfOnRight(withOperand: lhs, (/))
    }

    static func solveFrom(xSquared a: T, x b: T, c: T) -> QuadraticRoots {
        let discriminant = self.discriminantOf(xSquared: a, x: b, c: c)
        return (-b ± sqrt(discriminant)) / (2 * a)
    }
}

let a = 5 ± 10
print(a)
print(a + 2)
print(a - 2)
print(a * 2)

print(2 + a)
print(2 - a)
print(2 * a)

//print(a / 2)
```

Answer (score 3):

[`Numeric`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/numeric) only declares `+`, `-` and `*` operators. There is no `/` in `Numeric`. You need either [`BinaryInteger`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/binaryinteger) or [`FloatingPoint`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/floatingpoint) to get division.

For a quadratic equation solver, I would say `FloatingPoint` is more appropriate:

```
func / <T: FloatingPoint>(lhs: T, rhs: (T, T)) -> (T, T) {
    return (lhs / rhs.0, lhs / rhs.1)
}

func / <T: FloatingPoint>(lhs: (T, T), rhs: T) -> (T, T) {
    return (lhs.0 / rhs, lhs.1 / rhs)
}
```

As Alexander has said, it would be better if you created an enum representing the solutions:

```
enum QuadraticSolution {
    case none
    case one(value: Double)
    case two(value1: Double, value2: Double)
}

func quadratic(a: Double, b: Double, c: Double) -> QuadraticSolution {
    let discriminant = (b * b) - (4 * a * c)
    switch discriminant {
    case 0:
        return .one(value: -b / (2 * a))
    case let x where x < 0:
        return .none
    default:
        let twoSolutions = (-b ± sqrt(discriminant)) / (2 * a)
        return .two(value1: twoSolutions.0, value2: twoSolutions.1)
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the difference between `BinaryInteger` and `FloatingPoint`. Also what is the benefit to using one over the other?

Comment: @NoahWilder Do you want your solutions to come out as integers? If no, use `FloatingPoint`.

Comment: @NoahWilder Also, your first bonus question could be asked as a separate question that could be interesting, given you've put some effort into asking it. For the second one, check this out: https://www.wikihow.com/Solve-a-Cubic-Equation